# Were Luke and Kylo Ren thought to be the only Force users left in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-force

During *The Force Awakens*, we find out that

> Kylo Ren was once Luke's apprentice before going over to the Dark Side.

Until we discover

> Rey is also a force user,

are Kylo and Luke thought to be the only remaining Force users in the Galaxy?

Comment: Leia and Han both know who Snoke is, *and that he's a force user*.

Comment: Thought to be by who? Us out of universe of from a particular in universe perspective.

Comment: @JeremyFrench: I think we can assume this is asking in-universe.

Comment: @Richard Do you have more info / a source for that?

Comment: @Raidri They say so when discussing Ben's fall with each other.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**UPDATE 12/2017**

There's not yet canon proof, but there's a strong implication in *TLJ* that "a handful" of the Luke's Academy Jedi trainee students who left with Ben Solo after his tiff with Luke (and were already turning dark before that) became Knights of Ren. As such, there's a high probability they were still alive and thus were "force users left" during *TFA* timeline.

Additionally, there's also a strong implication that the stable boy at the end of *TLJ* used the Force to lift the broom, though that lacks definitive canon proof either.

---

- In the film, **we don't know of anyone who explicitly acknowledges any remaining Force users** aside from Kylo Ren and Rey.
- It's kind of implied by Ren that Snoke is a Force user, but even that is not stated 100% clearly, just that he "trained" Ren (and also implied when Snoke tells Ren to bring Rey to him when Ren fails to read her mind for the map).

  > KYLO REN
  >   Supreme Leader. I can get the map from the girl. I just need your guidance.
  >   SNOKE
  >   If what you say about this girl is true, bring her to me
- Maz Kanata comes close to outing herself but doesn't quite do it:

  > MAZ
  >   The belonging you seek is not behind you. It is ahead.
  >   **I am no Jedi, but I know the Force.**

  We know from *narrator* - e.g. Visual Dictonary - that Maz Kanata is Force Sensitive. But we don't know that anyone in TGFFA knows of that except for Maz herself; and her words to Rey can easily be interpreted as simply knowing stuff about the Force theoretically, the way Han talks about it.
- Nobody knows if Knights of Ren are Force Sensitive as of now. Nobody knows what happened to Inquisitors, or Kanan and Ezra, or any other Jedi that may have survived Order 66.
- In the trailer - but the line wasn't used in the film - Luke's voice acknoweldges that Leia has the Force *(and obviously, Leia knows she does from the end of Episode VI)*

  > The Force is strong in my family... my sister has it.
- Snoke *implicitly* acknowledges that there are other Force users, because Luke will train more Jedi:

  > SNOKE
  >   ... Leading them to the last Jedi.
  >   If Skywalker returns, **the new Jedi will rise.**
  >   (*WGA script*)
  >
  > Seated in shadow, the tall, slender form loomed over the other two men. Other than the face, only long, spindly fingers showed from beneath the dark robe. “The droid will soon be in the hands of the Resistance,” Snoke declaimed, his voice deep, soothing, and very much that of someone in complete control, “giving the enemy the means to locate Skywalker and bring to their cause a most powerful ally. **If Skywalker returns, the new Jedi will rise**.”
  >   (*Foster Novelization*)
- Obviously, from prior canon (Prequels), we can surmise that Force sensitive children keep being born, but that isn't stated as known truth in Episode VII except as implication of the last point.

Comment: It is interesting that nobody mentions Leia as a force user. I wonder if it is not know, or just not mentioned.

Comment: @jeremy in most eu/legends canon it is not widely known till far later.

Comment: Maz says in the film that she "knows the force" but isn't a Jedi.

Comment: @PointlessSpike - Yep. We can't tell for sure just from the film if she speaks about being Force Sensitive, or just knowing about the Force theoretically, like Han; but Visual Dictionary confirmed the former.

Comment: I think Snoke feeling Reys' awakening shows that he is a force user.

Comment: @DVK- Of course, that doesn't rule out the possibility that Han may be aware of a force talent in her, as he seems to know her well and he has experience with force-users. But I'm obsessing.

Comment: @JeremyFrench - that can be inferred. But not outright stated as a fact (just as the Emperor being Force Sensitive wasn't - IIRC - clear till Episode VI). He says things that a Force Sensitive would say, but doesn't show actual ability - maybe someone else told him that the Force awoke. May be he has Midichlorian meter :)

Comment: @JeremyFrench- Does he say he felt it? IIRC he said "There has been an awakening in the force." Could be either way.

Comment: What about Lor San Tekka?

Comment: @Raphael - as far as I can tell, he's NOT Force Sensitive, just a member of a sect that respects the Force and Jedi.

Comment: @DVK Thanks. I thought "Church of the Force" was some organized group of Force-sensitives.

Comment: being mentioned in the film vs characters in the film who implictly know or do not are different things entirely. the OP question is completely vague and as it sits has no answer whatsoever.

Comment: @Octopus - I would say that the fact that OP accepted this answer is at least an indication that it addresses what OP was looking for? :)

Answer (score 12):

So there are some known (to us) force users. Leia, Snoke even Maz at least.

In universe it would depend on who you are.

**Most of the general public**

Would not know if the Jedi really existed. Luke Skywalker is a legend. The force is a little known religion. Kylo Ren seems little known, even if he was he may not be a known force user.

**Someone with intimate knowledge of the Resistance and First order**

Consider Lor San Tekka for this point of view.

He knows of Luke and Kylo Ren. He is also likely to be able to assume that there are a number other people with force affinity who have been born, since the empires purges, but not trained (or awakened).

He may or may not be aware of Leia and Snoke being force sensitive.

**Trained force users**

Every other force user seems to be aware of the others we know of. Leia knows Kylo Ren is still alive. Snoke knows Luke is.

It has been shown a number of times that using the force creates a disturbance. Vader and Palpataine could sense Luke once he started using the force. Snoke and Ren can sense Rey.

So they would be very aware of new force users. If there were others who were actively using the force (and not masking it) it would become very obvious.

The fact that Rey's awakening is so clearly and quickly noticed shows that there are unlikely to be many (if any) other active force users in existence.

As Snoke makes clear that Luke is the last **Jedi**.

Comment: I think the question asked about "thought to be" in universe, not "known to us out of universe". E.g. nobody knows in universe that Maz is Force-sensitive (at least, not from known canon) - we are told by the narrator

Comment: Doesn't she tell Rey "I know a little of the force", though that is not clearly saying she knows how to use it.

Comment: exactly what you said in the comment. San Lor Tekka also **knew** of the Force but IIRC isn't force sensitive

Comment: The Jedi don't breed, but there's a definite family inheritance. Those who don't make the grade as Jedi recruits are left in-situ in the hopes that their offspring will be stronger.

Comment: Who said Jedi don't breed? Half the EU/Legends Jedi had Jedi ancestors. Or 90%. Even in prequels, Jedi aren't allowed **attachments**, but artificial insemination or one-night stands seem quite OK by Jedi Code :)

Comment: @DVK So whenever an OR Jedi had the urge, (s)he just.... ehm... followed *the will of the Force* and threw the other person away afterwards so not to get attached? Hmmm... no wonder the general public could be so easily convinced by Palpy that the Jedi were evil, wanted to take over the galaxy and had to be exterminated :P

Comment: @BMWurm - Best. breakup. Excuse. Ever.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it because

> Luke was training a group of Jedi. Ben perverted this and became Master of the Knights of Ren. There is then a shot of Kylo with the other Knights of Ren, they may have light sabres, though whatever they are holding are not ignited. 
>  Due to the comments of Snoke about "Even the Master of the Knights of Ren..." when talking about the force implies that the other Knights of Ren to be force users as well

Comment: "they have lightsabres" I only recall Kylo having one. There was a pic of scene floating around somewhere, maybe add it to the answer if it had more than one?

Comment: @Relix you are right, Ren is the only one with a visible light sabre. Others are holding staffs and batons that could be light sabres but they are not ignited so cannot tell for sure. Editing answer to reflect

Comment: AFAIK there are two competing theories about the Knights of Ren, with no evidence either way yet. One (my preferred) is that Ben "destroyed" Luke's Jedi training scheme by corrupting them to the dark side to *become* the knights, killing those who didn't join him. So they'd be force users. The other is that he "destroyed" Luke's work by killing them all, and the Knights are just his coincidental emo buddies. Might be force users, might not.

Comment: They COULD be force sensitive, just not possessing light sabres. Remember, Kylo Ren has a light sabre with a cracked crystal. This means he probably only had access to getting a single light sabre, and was stuck with one that needs to emit out the vents on the side (that is why it is crossed). This implies maybe there aren't many light sabres accessible in the universe, so they could be force sensitive without any light sabres. Also makes sense that if there is only one, the leader would possess it.

Comment: Also note how badly Ren wanted that sabre when Rey was disarmed from it in their fight, he was sick of having the cracked crystal sabre and wanted the sabre that boths works and belonged to Vader

Comment: @LucasCrawford I think ren wants the light sabre because it is another artefact of vaders